# Listagg function with PLSQL collection

Tags: oracle, collections, plsql, oracle11g, aggregate-functions

I have a PL/SQL collection of following type

```
type p_typ_str_tab is table of varchar2(4000) index by pls_integer;
```

I would like to aggregate the values into a single string with a simple inline function like `LISTAGG` without writing any custom functions or for loops.  All examples of `LISTAGG` don't show how to use PL/SQL collections.  I'm using Oracle 11g R2. Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To be able to use `LISTAGG` function with a collection, the collection must be declared as nested table not as an associative array and must be created as sql type (schema object) because it's not possible to use pl/sql type in a select statement. To that end you might do the following:

```
--- create a nested table type
SQL> create or replace type t_tb_type is table of number;
  2  /

Type created


--- and use it as follows
SQL> select listagg(column_value, ',') within group(order by column_value) res
  2    from table(t_tb_type(1,2,3)) -- or call the function that returns data of 
  3  /                              -- t_tb_type type

RES
-------
1,2,3
```

Otherwise the `loop` is your only choice.

Answer (score 5):

`LISTAGG` is an analytic SQL function, and those don't operate against PL/SQL collections, but cursors/rowsets.

So, in short, no, it's not possible.

That said, iterating over a PL/SQL table to build a concatenated string is trivial:

```
l_new_string := null;
for i in str_tab.first .. str_tab.last
loop
  if str_tab(i) is not null then
    l_new_string := str_tab(i) || ', ';
  end if;
end loop;
-- trim off the trailing comma and space
l_new_string := substr(l_new_string, 1, length(l_new_string) - 2);
```

Comment: so trivial and you even made a mistake ;)  your final string contains only last  entry ->
    l_new_string := l_new_string || str_tab(i) || ', '